# How to improve performance of the cleanup of the history tables of the Activity engine

Tags: activiti

I do have an application based on the [Activiti engine](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti) in version 5.22. Currently, it produces in a given time frame more history information than the history cleanup process is able to delete in the same time frame. Is there any idea how to improve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The default cleanup process

The Activity framework creates history data in the following tables:

- `ACT_HI_PROCINST`
- `ACT_HI_ACTINST`
- `ACT_HI_TASKINST`
- `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY`
- `ACT_HI_VARINST`
- `ACT_HI_DETAIL`
- `ACT_HI_COMMENT`
- `ACT_HI_ATTACHMENT`
- `ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK`

The default cleanup process fetches the `ACT_HI_PROCINST` and then tries to delete them, along with the other history tables, that are linked to a given `ACT_HI_PROCINST`. The delete process doesn't use batching or bulk deletes, hence it's very slow.

### Using a Stored Procedure to cleanup history data

One way to speed up the cleanup process is to execute a Stored Procedure, like the following one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DeleteActivityHistory(
    @BeforeStartTimestamp DATETIME,
    @BatchSize INT,
    @DeletedRowCount INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN                         
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_TABLE;
    CREATE TABLE #ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_TABLE (PROC_INST_ID_ NVARCHAR(64));
    
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE;
    CREATE TABLE #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE (PROC_INST_ID_ NVARCHAR(64));

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE;
    CREATE TABLE #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE (ID_ NVARCHAR(64));
                                                   
    INSERT INTO #ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_TABLE
    SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) PROC_INST_ID_
    FROM ACT_HI_PROCINST
    WHERE
        END_TIME_ <= @BeforeStartTimestamp
        AND END_TIME_ IS NOT NULL
        AND SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ IS NULL;
        
    SET @DeletedRowCount=0;
    DECLARE @DeletedBatchRowCount INT;
                    
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_TABLE) > 0
    BEGIN
        TRUNCATE TABLE #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE;
        TRUNCATE TABLE #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE;
        
        SET @DeletedBatchRowCount=0;
                        
        WITH ACT_HI_PROCINST_HIERARCHY(PROC_INST_ID_)
        AS (
            SELECT PROC_INST_ID_
            FROM #ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_TABLE
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ACT_HI_PROCINST.PROC_INST_ID_
            FROM ACT_HI_PROCINST
            INNER JOIN ACT_HI_PROCINST_HIERARCHY ON ACT_HI_PROCINST_HIERARCHY.PROC_INST_ID_ = ACT_HI_PROCINST.SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_
        )
        INSERT INTO #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE
        SELECT PROC_INST_ID_
        FROM ACT_HI_PROCINST_HIERARCHY;
        
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            
            DELETE FROM ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY
            WHERE ID_ IN (
                SELECT BYTEARRAY_ID_ FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL
                WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE)
            );
            
            SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
            
            DELETE FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL
            WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE);
                       
            SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
            
            DELETE FROM ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY
            WHERE ID_ IN (
                SELECT BYTEARRAY_ID_ FROM ACT_HI_VARINST
                WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE)
            );
            
            SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
            
            DELETE FROM ACT_HI_VARINST
            WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE);
                                                          
            SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
            
            DELETE FROM ACT_HI_ACTINST
            WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE);
                       
            SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
            
            -- Delete ACT_HI_TASKINST rows recursive along with their associated: 
            -- ACT_HI_DETAIL, ACT_HI_VARINST, ACT_HI_COMMENT, ACT_HI_ATTACHMENT, ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK
            BEGIN
                WITH ACT_HI_TASKINST_HIERARCHY(ID_)
                AS (
                    SELECT ID_
                    FROM ACT_HI_TASKINST
                    WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE)
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT ACT_HI_TASKINST.ID_
                    FROM ACT_HI_TASKINST
                    INNER JOIN ACT_HI_TASKINST_HIERARCHY ON ACT_HI_TASKINST_HIERARCHY.ID_ = ACT_HI_TASKINST.PARENT_TASK_ID_
                )
                INSERT INTO #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE
                SELECT ID_
                FROM ACT_HI_TASKINST_HIERARCHY;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY
                WHERE ID_ IN (
                    SELECT BYTEARRAY_ID_ FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL
                    WHERE TASK_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE)
                );
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL
                WHERE TASK_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE);
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY
                WHERE ID_ IN (
                    SELECT BYTEARRAY_ID_ FROM ACT_HI_VARINST
                    WHERE TASK_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE)
                );
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_HI_VARINST
                WHERE TASK_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE);
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_HI_COMMENT
                WHERE TASK_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE);
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY
                WHERE ID_ IN (
                    SELECT CONTENT_ID_ FROM ACT_HI_ATTACHMENT
                    WHERE TASK_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE)
                );
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_HI_ATTACHMENT
                WHERE TASK_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE);
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK
                WHERE TASK_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE);
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
                DELETE FROM ACT_HI_TASKINST
                WHERE ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE);
                           
                SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                
            END;
                   
            DELETE FROM ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK
            WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE);
                       
            SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                       
            DELETE FROM ACT_HI_COMMENT
            WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE);
                       
            SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                       
            DELETE FROM ACT_HI_PROCINST
            WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_ FROM #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE);
                       
            SET @DeletedBatchRowCount+=@@ROWCOUNT;
                                                       
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            SET @DeletedRowCount+=@DeletedBatchRowCount;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
                -- The current transaction cannot be committed.
                BEGIN
                    PRINT
                        N'The transaction cannot be committed. Rolling back transaction.'
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                END;
            ELSE
                IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
                -- The current transaction can be committed.
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT
                            N'Exception was caught, but the trasaction can be committed.'
                        COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
                    END;
        END CATCH;
                   
        TRUNCATE TABLE #ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_TABLE;
        
        INSERT INTO #ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_TABLE
        SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) PROC_INST_ID_
        FROM ACT_HI_PROCINST
        WHERE
            END_TIME_ <= @BeforeStartTimestamp
            AND END_TIME_ IS NOT NULL
            AND SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ IS NULL;
    END
    
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_TABLE;                
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PROC_INST_ID_TABLE;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TASK_INST_ID_TABLE;
END
```

This stored procedure has the following advantages:

- it uses a single database connection, hence network traffic is reduced to a bare minum
- it uses one transaction per batch, hence it avoid growing the transaction log to large or having locks being taken for too long, for which SQL Server could escalate them to table locks.
- it uses bulk delete SQL queries instead of deleting each row individually

You can execute this Stroed Procedure using JDBC, like this:

```
public int deleteActivityHistoryBeforeDate(
        Connection connection, 
        Timestamp olderThanTimestamp, 
        int batchSize) {
    long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
    try (CallableStatement sp = connection.prepareCall(
            "{ call usp_DeleteActivityHistory(?, ?, ?) }")
    ) {
        sp.setTimestamp(1, olderThanTimestamp);
        sp.setInt(2, batchSize);
        sp.registerOutParameter("DeletedRowCount", Types.INTEGER);
        sp.execute();
        int rowCount = sp.getInt("DeletedRowCount");
        LOGGER.info(
            "Deleted {} records in {} milliseconds", 
            rowCount,
            TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - startNanos)
        );
        return rowCount;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("The usp_DeleteActivityHistory execution failed", e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The `connection` parameter is the JDBC `Connection` the procedure will execute on.

The `olderThanTimestamp` is a `Timestamp` object that tells what's the maximum timestamp value for the `END_TIME_` column in `ACT_HI_PROCINST` table up to which the history records are deleted.

The `batchSize` parameter tells how many root `ACT_HI_PROCINST` records are deleted in one transaction. After executing a batch, the process proceeds to the next one until no root `ACT_HI_PROCINST` row, older than the `olderThanTimestamp` value, is present in the database.

The return value contains the number of table records across all tables that were deleted by executing the stored procedure with the provided parameter values.

### Example on GitHub

If you want to see how the Stored Procedure works in practice, check out [this test case on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/78aa3fe9787866a5214dd9460534c9b8e2e3dece/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/sp/ActivityHistorySQLServerStoredProcedureTest.java).